# Class 'Imagick' not found in ZF2

Tags: php, image, zend-framework2, imagick

I'm trying to instantiate `Imagick` in a service class, however, I keep getting the following error message:

> **Class 'Imagick' not found in Gallery/Service/ImageUploadService.php**

I've run `convert -version` and I get the following response:

> Version: ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 2018-07-10 Q16
>   http://www.imagemagick.org Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2012
>   ImageMagick Studio LLC Features: OpenMP

Here's my service class:

```
<?php
namespace Gallery\Service;


class ImageUploadService
{
    private $Imagick;
    private $pdflib;

    public function __construct($pdflib)
    {
        $this->Imagick = new \Imagick();
        $this->pdflib = $pdflib;
    }

    public function registerImage()
    {
        return 'success';
    }

    private function checkFileType()
    {

    }

    private function sanitizeFileName()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: I think it does not run inside `__construct()`

Comment: @Mohammad I tried instantiating it in the `registerImage()` function instead but it still gave me the same error

Comment: actived Imagick in cpanel or php.ini ?

Comment: Imagick is not the same as Imagemagick; it is a php API. Do you know for a fact whether Imagick is installed?

Comment: @Bonzo As I wrote in the description, I did run `convert -version` and it did give me an ImageMagick version. I have found a solution and am currently writing an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran several of the commands I saw online but to keep it short, running the first command in the following fixed the issue for me:

```
sudo apt install libmagickwand-dev imagemagick php-dev 
sudo pecl install imagick 
sudo apt-get install php5.6-imagick 
sudo service php5.6-fpm restart
```